# Word2vec CBOW model with negative sampling

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec, bag-of-words

From [this article](https://aegis4048.github.io/optimize_computational_efficiency_of_skip-gram_with_negative_sampling#Softmax-is-computationally-very-expensive):

> - In vanilla skip gram model, softmax is computationally very expensive, as
>   it requires scanning through the entire output embedding matrix (W_output) to compute the probability distribution of all V words, where V can be millions or more.
> - Furtheremore, the normalization factor in the denominator also requires V iterations.

Hence the article suggests applying negative sampling instead of softmax. There are many article discussing skip grams with negative sampling. But I did not find any discussing CBOW (Continuous Bag of Words Model ) model with negative sampling. Why is this so? Is it not possible / recommended? Or its exacty same as skip gram? Can you please shed some insights about using negative sampling with CBOW?

PS: any article / paper link will also be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the perspective of finding relevant article[s] this one seems aligned:  [NLP’s word2vec: Negative Sampling Explained](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/nlps-word2vec-negative-sampling) . The article seems to address the topics you mention. In particular :  skip-grams, computational questions, negative sampling, and the objective function to optimize.

As far as being able to follow it there *are* gaps in its explanations: so it is a bit of gymnastics to read it.

Comment: Thats specific to negative sampling in the context of skip gram and have come across it earlier. I am looking for details of using negative sampling in CBOW. I believe there wont be much difference. I guess I understand negative sampling quite well, at least in the context of skip grams. I guess I should try it myself, implementation of negative sampling in CBOW. May be I succeed or I fail and come up with fresh doubts...

Comment: OK let us know what you find out!